# counts none unique records in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 Tables:

Table1:

```
CustomerID   CustomerName              Address           IP
================================================================
87           Wartian Herkku           Torikatu 38        1.1.1.1
567          Wartian Herkku           Torikatu 38        1.1.1.1
778          Wartian Herkku           Torikatu 38        1.1.1.1
88           Wellington Importadora   Rua do Mercado, 4  2.2.2.2
6732         Wellington Importadora   Rua do Mercado, 4  2.2.2.2
10           White Clover Markets     305 - 14th Ave. 5  3.3.3.3
```

Table2:

```
CustomerID   CustomerName           Address             IP
==============================================================
778          Wartian Herkku           Torikatu 38        1.1.1.1
6732         Wellington Importadora   Rua do Mercado, 4  2.2.2.2
10           White Clover Markets     305 - 14th Ave. 5  3.3.3.3
```

Table1 has customers with more than one customerID but the IP is unique. After merging the customerID from Table1 I get Table2.
I want the counts of resolved recordsin Table2 that has only one entry in Table1 in SQL (Oracle)??

If both tables should have a column like "City", such as 
City
========
London
London
London
Paris
Paris
New York

How could the solution look like???

Comment: suggestion: include `create table` and `insert` commands to build those tables so we can work on examples at our end more easily.  Thanks

Comment: For better explanation add the result you require

Comment: Edit your question and provide the code for going from Table1 to Table2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a having clause with a condition on `count` to find the records with one occurrence in table1, and then filter table2 by it with an `in` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table2
WHERE  CustomerName IN (SELECT   CustomerName
                        FROM     table1
                        GROUP BY CustomerName
                        HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Comment: If both tables should have a column like "City" please see my the modified sample above: How could the solution look like???

Answer (score 0):

The "direct" answer to your question would seem to be:

```
select count(*)
from table2 t2
where t2.CustomerName in (select t1.CustomerName
                          from Table1 t1
                          group by t1.CustomerName
                          having count(*) = 1
                         );
```